# activerecord's starting ids are high for RAILS_ENV=test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, primary-key

I've noticed that ids are in the high range for the `test` database of my Rails app. I'm wondering why this is the case. In development my ids start at 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that each test is wrapped in a transaction, which gets rolled back. Even though the records are deleted, the IDs are reserved and therefore the next one is auto-incremented.

If this bothers you, you can truncate the tables like this: `truncate table_name;`.

Comment: Still, I don't think I inserted _that_ many records, but I believe you :)

Comment: You may be surprised how quickly they creep up, especially when running autotest!